# Odd behaviour when applying `Pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds`

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that is of `Timedelta` type. I used groupby with a separate month column to create groups of these `Timdelta` by month, I then tried to use the `agg` function along with `min, max, mean` on the `Timedelta` column which triggered `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

As a solution for this I tried to use the `total_seconds()` function along with `apply()` to get a numeric representation of the column, however the behaviour seems strange to me as the `NaT` values in my `Timedelta` column were turned into `-9.223372e+09` but they result in `NaN` when `total_seconds()` is used on a scalar without `apply()`

A minimal example:

```
test = pd.Series([np.datetime64('nat'),np.datetime64('nat')])
res = test.apply(pd.Timedelta.total_seconds)
print(res)
```

which produces:

```
0   -9.223372e+09
1   -9.223372e+09
dtype: float64
```

whereas:

```
res = test.iloc[0].total_seconds()
print(res)
```

yields:

```
nan
```

The behaviour of the second example is desired as I wish to perform aggregations etc and propagate missing/invalid values. Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `.dt.total_seconds()` method, instead of applying `pd.Timedelta.total_seconds` function onto `datetime64[ns]` dtype column:

```
In [232]: test
Out[232]:
0   NaT
1   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]  # <----

In [233]: pd.to_timedelta(test)
Out[233]:
0   NaT
1   NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]  # <----

In [234]: pd.to_timedelta(test).dt.total_seconds()
Out[234]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Another demo:

```
In [228]: s = pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(['03:33:33','1 day','aaa'], errors='coerce'))

In [229]: s
Out[229]:
0   0 days 03:33:33
1   1 days 00:00:00
2               NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [230]: s.dt.total_seconds()
Out[230]:
0    12813.0
1    86400.0
2        NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ok, but `pd.NaT` does have a `pd.NaT.total_seconds()` method which does return `NaN`, so it's counterintuitive, we'd expect it to work.

Comment: Is there actually also the other way around possible? Atm I convert a timestamp to numeric values via pd.to_timedelta().dt.total_seconds() but after some calculations I would like to re-convert it.

Comment: @Ben, it depends on what exactly do you have (your dataset) and on what exactly do you want to get ;)

Comment: I have a time format in "2018-02-05 13:00:00" which I convert to "1.517839e+09". Can I re-convert that?

Comment: Awesome,..  that was obvious :) Thanks!